# Reference: Comparing PHP's print and echo

Tags: php, echo

What is the difference between PHP's `print` and `echo`?

Stack Overflow has many questions asking about PHP's `print` and `echo` keyword usage.

The purpose of this post is to provide a canonical [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)  question and answer about PHP's `print` and `echo` keywords and compare their differences and use-cases.

Comment: I think here is not enough about print returning value. Print is usefull for fast debug output or something like it: strpos($x,$y)!==FALSE OR print "something". Fast to type and good to read. And "Is print a function" was awkward to read for some reason(your argumentaion seems ... strange and not obvious) - it is language construct, there is far worse thing you can't do with it: variable functions.

Comment: To keep this open what needs to be done here is: 1. split into a question and answer. 2. Reference/link to existing content about the subject matter on Stack Overflow (kinda like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) but in the answer. 3. Needs to be CW.

Comment: The "Related Column" is fine, but it's not very focused. To increase its value as a canonical reference question and answer then it should also be well researched and links to other specific good answers would add value.

Comment: The question really needs to be an actual _question_. I can add a banner to it regarding the canonical part once you're done.

Answer (score 194):

### Why two constructs?

The truth about *print* and *echo* is that while they appear to users as two distinct constructs, they are both really shades of echo if you get down to basics, i.e. look at the internal source code. That source code involves the parser as well as opcode handlers. Consider a simple action such as displaying the number zero.  Whether you use echo or print, the same handler " ZEND_ECHO_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER" will be invoked.  The handler for print does one thing before it invokes the handler for echo, it makes sure that the return value for print is 1, as follows:

```
ZVAL_LONG(&EX_T(opline->result.var).tmp_var, 1);
```

(see [here for reference](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h#2412))

The return value is a convenience should one wish to use print in a conditional expression. Why 1 and not 100?  Well in PHP the truthiness of 1 or 100 is the same, i.e. true, whereas 0 in a boolean context equates as a false value. In PHP all non-zero values (positive and negative) are truthy values and this derives from PHP's Perl legacy.

But, if this is the case, then one may wonder why echo take multiple arguments whereas print can only handle one.  For this answer we need to turn to the parser, specifically the file **zend_language_parser.y**.  You will note that echo has the flexibility built in so that it may print one or multiple expressions (see [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#734)). whereas print is constrained to printing only one expression (see [there](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#850)).

### Syntax

In the C programming language and languages influenced by it such as PHP, there is a distinction between statements and expressions. Syntactically, `echo expr, expr, ... expr` is a statement while `print expr` is an expression since it evaluates to a value. Therefore, like other statements, `echo expr` stands on its own and is incapable of inclusion in an expression:

```
5 + echo 6;   // syntax error
```

In contrast, `print expr`, can alone form a statement:

```
print 5; // valid
```

Or, be part of an expression:

```
   $x = (5 + print 5); // 5 
   var_dump( $x );     // 6
```

One might be tempted to think of `print` as if it were a unary operator, like `!` or `~` however it is not an operator.  What `!, ~ and print` have in common is that they are all built into PHP and each takes only one argument. You can use `print` to create the following weird but valid code:

```
    <?php 
    print print print print 7; // 7111
```

At first glance the result may seem odd that the last print statement prints its operand of '7' *first*.  But, if you dig deeper and look at the actual opcodes it makes sense:

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   PRINT                                            ~0      7
         1      PRINT                                            ~1      ~0
         2      PRINT                                            ~2      ~1
         3      PRINT                                            ~3      ~2
         4      FREE                                                     ~3
         5    > RETURN                                                   1
```

The very first opcode that gets generated is that corresponding to the 'print 7'.  The '~0' is a temporary variable whose value is 1.  That variable becomes and operand for the next print opcode which in turn returns a temporary variable and the process repeats.  The last temporary variable doesn't get used at all so, it gets freed.

### Why does `print` return a value and `echo` doesn't?

Expressions evaluate to values.  For example `2 + 3` evaluates to `5`, and `abs(-10)` evaluates to `10`. Since `print expr` is itself an expression, then it should hold a value and it does, a consistent value of `1` indicates a truthy result and by returning a non-zero value the expression becomes useful for inclusion in another expression. For example in this snippet, the return value of print is useful in determining a function sequence:

```
<?php

function bar( $baz ) { 
   // other code   
}
function foo() {
  return print("In and out ...\n");
}

if ( foo() ) {

     bar();
}
```

You might find print of particular value when it comes to debugging on the fly, as the next example illustrates:

```
<?php
$haystack = 'abcde';
$needle = 'f';
strpos($haystack,$needle) !== FALSE OR print "$needle not in $haystack"; 

// output: f not in abcde
```

As a side-note, generally, statements are not expressions; they don't return a value. The exception, of course are expression statements which use print and even simple expressions used as a statement, such as`1;`, a syntax which PHP inherits from C.  The expression statement may look odd but it is very helpful, making it possible to pass arguments to functions.

### Is `print` a function?

No, it is a language construct.  While all function calls are expressions, `print (expr)` is an expression, despite the visual which appears as if it were using function call syntax.  In truth these parentheses are parentheses-expr syntax, useful for expression evaluation. That accounts for the fact that at times they are optional if the expression is a simple one, such as `print "Hello, world!"`.  With a more complex expression such as `print (5 ** 2 + 6/2); // 28` the parentheses aid the evaluation of the expression. Unlike function names, [`print` is syntactically a keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), and semantically a ["language construct"](http://www.php.net/print).

The term "language construct" in PHP usually refers to "pseudo" functions like `isset` or `empty`. Although these "constructs" look exactly like functions, they are actually [fexprs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr), that is, the arguments are passed to them without being evaluated, which requires special treatment from the compiler. `print` happens to be an fexpr that chooses to evaluate its argument in the same way as a function.

The difference can be seen by printing `get_defined_functions()`: there is no `print` function listed. (Though `printf` and friends are: unlike `print`, they are true functions.)

### Why does print(foo) work then?

For the same reason that`echo(foo)` works. These parentheses are quite different from function call parentheses because they pertain to expressions instead.  That is why one may code `echo ( 5 + 8 )` and can expect a result of 13 to display (see [reference](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#1083)). These parenthesis are involved in evaluating an expression rather than invoking a function.  Note: there are other uses for parentheses in PHP, such as if if-conditional expressions, assignment lists, function declarations, etc.

### Why do `print(1,2,3)` and `echo(1,2,3)` result in syntax errors?

The syntax is `print expr`, `echo expr` or `echo expr, expr, ..., expr`. When PHP encounters `(1,2,3)`, it tries to parse it as a single expression and fails, because unlike C, PHP does not really have a binary comma operator; the comma serves more as a separator.  ( You may find a binary comma nonetheless in PHP's for-loops, syntax it inherited from C.)

### Semantics

The statement `echo e1, e2, ..., eN;` can be understood as syntactic sugar for `echo e1; echo e2; ...; echo eN;`.

Since all expressions are statements, and `echo e` always has the same side-effects as `print e`, and the return value of `print e` is ignored when used as a statement, we can understand `echo e` as syntactic sugar for `print e`.

These two observations mean that `echo e1, e2, ..., eN;` can be seen as syntactic sugar for `print e1; print e2; ... print eN;`. (However, note the non-semantic runtime differences below.)

We therefore only have to define the semantics for `print`. `print e`, when evaluated:

1. evaluates its single argument `e` and [type-casts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the resulting value to a string `s`. (Thus, `print e` is equivalent to `print (string) e`.)
2. Streams the string `s` to [the output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) (which eventually will be streamed to the standard output).
3. Evaluates to the integer `1`.

### Differences at the bytecode level

`print` involves a small overhead of populating the return variable (pseudocode)

```
print 125;

PRINT  125,$temp     ; print 125 and place 1 in $temp 
UNSET  $temp         ; remove $temp
```

single `echo` compiles to one opcode:

```
echo 125;

ECHO 125
```

multi-value `echo` compiles to multiple opcodes

```
echo 123, 456;

ECHO 123
ECHO 456
```

Note that multi-value `echo` doesn't concatenate its arguments, but outputs them one-by-one.

Reference: [`zend_do_print`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_compile.c#L852), [`zend_do_echo`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_compile.c#L865).

### Runtime differences

[`ZEND_PRINT`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L988) is implemented as follows (pseudocode)

```
PRINT  var, result:

    result = 1
    ECHO var
```

So it basically puts `1` in the result variable and delegates the real job to the `ZEND_ECHO` handler. [`ZEND_ECHO`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L969) does the following

```
ECHO var:

    if var is object
        temp = var->toString()
        zend_print_variable(temp)
    else
        zend_print_variable(var)
```

where `zend_print_variable()` performs the actual "printing" (in fact, it merely redirects to a dedicated SAPI function).

### Speed: `echo x` vs `print x`

Unlike **echo**, **print** allocates a temporary variable.  However, the amount of time spent on this activity is minuscule, so the difference between these two language constructs is negligible.

### Speed: `echo a,b,c` vs `echo a.b.c`

The first one compiles down to three separate statements. The second evaluates the entire expression `a.b.c.`, prints the result and disposes it immediately. Since concatenation involves memory allocations and copying, the first option will be more efficient.

### So which one to use?

In web applications, output is mostly concentrated in templates. Since templates use `<?=`, which is the alias of `echo`, it seems logical to stick to `echo` in other parts of code as well. `echo` has an additional advantage of being able to print multiple expression without concatenating them and doesn't involve an overhead of populating a temporary return variable. So, use `echo`.

Comment: I've extensively edited and clarified this, and added a section on semantics. I'm fairly confident on it, but someone could double-check it.

Comment: Does this mean, then, that it's better to use `echo $a,$b,$c` for concatenation of string vars? I've honestly never seen this in use.

Comment: How about a TL;DR section describing functional differences? Like: `print` allows only one arguments, `echo` may have multiple; `echo` can't be a part of an expression while `print` can and returns ...; and may be some some performance summary. And all those "why" and "under the hood" parts afterwards

Answer (score 0):

`print` may live as statement without the need of ;, and this is the reason that we may include it in a `$b; print "TRUE": print "FALSE";`