# PHP practical advantages for using echo over print

Tags: php, performance, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference: Comparing PHP's print and echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo)

I am wondering about the *practical* and *real* advantages and reasons for using `echo` instead of `print` to write output to the screen.

In many areas of my code I have this sort of thing:

```
PRINT("<b>".$course_id."</b>");
```

I understand that `print` returns a value whereas `echo` doesn't, however i'm interested to know if there is any real reason to replace the instances in my code (and there are a few unfortunately) of `print` with `echo`?

Is it just bad practice to use `print` in these sort of scenarios or is there reason and benefit to avoiding it?

I am using PHP 5.3.13.

Comment: From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_print.asp):

Tip: The print() function is slightly slower than echo().

Comment: print returns 1 always, but its slower than echo( and echo does not return anything)

Comment: One more difference : echo can take more than one parameter when used without parentheses. Note that echo ($arg1,$arg2) is invalid. And print only takes one parameter.

Comment: they are both [language constructs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in) and print should be insignificantly slower than echo. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo) question should cover most of the details in depth, but in short there should be no reason to go through the overhead of replacing you print with echo to get a negligible performance improvement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [phpbench](http://www.phpbench.com/), `echo()` is faster than `print()`. But I think nobody will notice if your code is a few microseconds slower.

Comment: Please help us and start with looking for duplicates just leaving a link to it in a comment under the question. Thank you for your help and keep sharing the love!

Comment: And btw, phpbench is not an authorative resource. The motivation of it's webmaster is highly questionable and scientifically it's well, idiocracy.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to 'echo' print returns a value, so

```
touch ($file) || print "Could not create $file";
```

is permitted but

```
touch ($file) || echo "Could not create $file";
```

is not.

According to Fabien Potencier 'print' uses one more opcode because it actually returns something:
http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster

So 'echo' should be a little, little bit faster than 'print'. I think most developers prefer echo to print, because using echo is a bit more flexible if you just want to render text.

You could replace the 'print'-calls with the search and replace-function of an IDE and a regex, if you desire to do so, but most of the performance bottlenecks of common applications are found elsewhere, i think.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is by far neglectable. There's no reason to refactor out uses of the print() function.