# Why do the"print" and "echo" functions not need brackets around them

Tags: php, function, printing, echo, brackets

Just wondering.

Thanks.

And I'm just putting this so I can reach the 30 characters, ignore this bit :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Comparing PHP's print and echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo)

Comment: They are not functions, they are *language constructs* and therein lies your answer. Unfortunately due to various bits and pieces of design stupidity over the years, the lack of requirement for parenthesis is not true of all language constructs. Some good further reading on the subject can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in)

Answer (score 7):

Because they are PHP structures (called also constructs) not functions

Answer (score 0):

*echo* is not actually a function it is a language construct, so you are not required to use parentheses with it. *echo* unlike some other language constructs does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function.

Because *echo* does not behave like a function, the following code is invalid.

```
($some_var) ? echo 'true' : echo 'false';
```

However, the following examples will work:

```
($some_var) ? print 'true' : print 'false';
```

*print* is also a construct, but it behaves like a function, so it may be used in this context.