# how to include the result of my java servlet in a php file?

Tags: java, php, html

Let's say I have two websites.  A Java web app running at www.server100.com, and a PHP web app running at www.server200.com.

Let's say I have a servlet `http://www.server100.com/webapp1/getImageServlet` that returns the following HTML content, where the filename in the html (`ABC123.jpg`) is a different filename for every hour of the day:

```
<div id="dynamicImage">
  <img src="http://www.server100.com/ABC123.jpg">
</div>
```

Now, let's say I have a PHP file here: `http://www.server200.com/test1.php`.  How do I include the HTML that results from the servlet in my PHP file?

I'm thinking I want to do something like ...

```
<?php
  Print "<html><body>";
  Print "Hi!  Let's see this hour's image!";
  include "http://www.server100.com/webapp1/getImageServlet";
  Print "</body></html>";
?>
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!  And would it simplify things if the Java app and the PHP app were running on the same server?  Thanks!

Comment: I might not understand question well, but PHP file can obtain also HTML just not in `<??>` tags, or in case you can `echo()` HTML out `<?php echo '<span>AHOY</span>'?>` anyway what is the output of `http://www.server100.com/webapp1/getImageServlet` ?

Comment: Pretty new to PHP, thanks for the help.  The .../getImageServlet returns the <div> block.

Comment: also please use `echo 'string';` or `echo $variable;` instead of `print()` see thread about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7094118/1564365).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out ...

`Print file_get_contents("http://www.server100.com/webapp1/getImageServlet");`

... seems to do what I need.

Comment: oh nice, you got it yourself ;) also note that `print()` is from Perl, you might take a look at [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 

    //your PHP goes here
        file_get_contents("http://www.server100.com/webapp1/getImageServlet");
    ?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

save this as `whatever.php`

---

if your servlet outputs HTML just do this

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("http://www.server100.com/webapp1/getImageServlet", "r"); 

$contents = '';

while (!feof($handle)) {

 $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);

}

fclose($handle);

echo $contents; //printing it all out

?>
```

also echoing [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) should work just fine

Comment: Thanks!  What about the `file_get_contents` code I posted in my answer below.  Does that do the same thing as you `fopen`?  Or are there problems with mine?  Thanks!

Comment: I think it is just fine. I didn't get question right at the first. And you answered while I was adding/editing mine answer.