# echo with print - unexpected answer

Tags: php, printing, echo

What is the output of the following code?

```
echo '1' . (print '2') + 3;
```

My answer was 15, but the answer is 214.

Why?

Comment: hi you can give minus votes , but please explain why 214 is coming ??

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo) may help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As executed, the code will do:

```
print '2'  -> outputs 2
... print ALWAYS has a return value of 1, so the code becomes

echo '1' . (1 + 3);  // with output '2'
```

This is simplified to

```
echo '1' . 4; // with output '2'
echo '14'; // output 2
```

final output: 214.