# Differences in concatenating strings

Tags: php, string, concatenation

What are the differences in the results of these three strings:

1. `echo "Hello" . "World! <br />";`
2. `echo "Hello"; echo "World!" , "<br />";`
3. `echo "Hello" , "World!" , "<br />";`

Is there any preferred way to concatenate strings or are they all acceptable?

Comment: 2. is no concatenation and since I'm unfimiliar with `,` I'm gonna go and say it is equivalent to `.`.

Comment: @kingkero It's not. :)

Comment: @kingkero it might not be concatenation but is there a different on the output? Is there a reason that you would prefer to do it another way?

Comment: The period (`.`) is the actual concatenation operator. The comma (`,`) is just passing multiple arguments to `echo` function (before someone corrects me, I know it is a language construct).

Comment: The comma is the fastest regarding performance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Comparing PHP's print and echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo)

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев:  In the real world, the difference between these two would be infinitesimal that you'd need at least a few thousand iterations to even know there's a performance difference. It's micro-optimization at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is to use the dot.

Most php programmers don't even know it is possible to use the comma. 
Having two echo statements is less readable, and slightly less performant.

Comment: It is also preferred to use 'single quotes' for simple strings.  Using double quotes evokes a small processing engine that parses the string looking for variable names and escape characters.

Comment: that makes so little difference it should never be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation operator is '.', the comma doesn't concatenate. In the examples you made, only the first one is concatenation.

On the other side, the echo construct, accepts many parameters which are separated by commas.