# Ternary operator not working if I am using echo

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am using this ternary operator:

```
$this->checkIfProductCategoriesContainsString($productId, $categoryNeedle) !== false ? echo "Category containing categoryNeedle exists" : echo "Category does not exist.";
```

I also tried it like this:

```
($this->checkIfProductCategoriesContainsString($productId, $categoryNeedle) !== false) ? echo "Category containing categoryNeedle exists" : echo "Category does not exist.";
```

But my IDE says `unexpected echo after ?`

Comment: Language? The ternary operator usually works for expressions than can be evaluated: `cond ? trueValue : falseVaue` as opposed to `cond ? doIfTrue : doIfFalse`. Does the echo function return something?

Comment: Then `echo` does not return anything, you can't use it like this but you can use `if else` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo) between `print` and `echo` in PHP in general. Tl;dr use [print](http://php.net/print) instead.

```
$this->checkIfProductCategoriesContainsString($productId, $categoryNeedle) ?
    print "Category containing category needle exists" : 
    print "Category does not exist.";
```

But it's better to just:

```
echo $this->checkIfProductCategoriesContainsString($productId, $categoryNeedle) ?
    'Category containing category needle exists' : 
    'Category does not exist.';
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
echo(
    $this->checkIfProductCategoriesContainsString($productId, $categoryNeedle) !== false
        ? "Category containing categoryNeedle exists"
        : "Category does not exist."
);
```