# Insert php echo value for name field

Tags: php, html, database

I want to submit checkbox value into database.

To insert data into database, how will I use $_POST['name_value'] for the 1st case as  when use for 2nd case I may use  to insert data into database $_POST['m']?

```
1st case: <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="<?php echo $days;?>[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>"></td>
2nd case: <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="m[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>"></td>
```

Comment: Don't echo the name. Instead, set a hard value for each field name. And use `print` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @milenmk Why `print` instead of `echo`? `echo` is more idiomatic in PHP.

Comment: @milenmk That's shell, not PHP.

Comment: @milenmk If I echo name, then what will be the problems?

Comment: @Barmar My bad. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878506/should-i-use-echo-or-print-in-php-scripts There are also a lot of other related articles and most people use print instead of echo.

Comment: @milenmk Huh? Most of the answers there say that echo is better.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that most PHP programmers use `print`? I think `echo` is overwhelmingly more common.

Comment: @milenmk Make sure you don't count `printf()` and `sprintf()`, they're used for different purposes.

Comment: @Bramar I know. As said, I always use `print`. Moreover, lately, I do a lot of customization of existing PHP codes and barely see `echo` being used.

Comment: @Barmar I've been using php since v4 (not professionally) and I almost never seen anyone use `print` instead of `echo`. @achalnaskar I'm not certain what's the problem here is, but why not use `<?=$days?>` and `<?=$id?>` respectively?